# REQUEST_URI RewriteCond Syntax

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am sure I am doing something silly here, but I can't seem to figure out what it is.

I can't understand why the RewriteCond for the {REQUEST_URI} isn't evaluating to true and thus preventing the RewriteRule from firing.  Instead, *given the following url, the rule fires and the user is always taken to https://www.diffsite.com*.

Any help would really be appreciated - and thanks in advance.

**url**:

```
http://www.regularsite.com/page-name/
```

**.htaccess code**:

```
# Use PHP5.4 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (iphone|ipod|android|symbian|windows\phone|blackberry|iemobile|opera\ mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^page-name/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.diffsite.com/ [L,R=302]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%{REQUEST_URI}` always matches a URI that starts with leading forward slash `/` so this will work for you:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/page-name/ [NC]
```

However in your rule `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}` is not even needed as you can do this negation in `RewriteRule` itself:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (iphone|ipod|android|symbian|windows\phone|blackberry|iemobile|opera\ mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile) [NC]
RewriteRule !^page-name/ https://www.diffsite.com/ [NC,L,R=302]
```

Not that inside `.htaccess` leading slash is not matched in `RewriteRule`.

Comment: Thanks!  Sorry it took a while to mark the answer here.  For some reason I didn't see an answer (or comment) had been posted.  Thanks again though.